# Htaccess redirect http or https from domain.com to https domain.net

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, url-rewriting

I have two domain for the same website one .com with ssl and the other .net without ssl
we would like to use the .com extension only and redirect our users from the old domain to the new one using the htaccess file (i tried using this code):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1       [QSA,L,R=301]

Rewritecond %{REMOTE_HOST}  \.exemple\.(net) [nc]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.exemple.com [r=301,nc]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.exemple.com/404
```

That obviously doesn't work!

```
exemple.net  ------>   https://www.exemple.com/404
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably use `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{REMOTE_HOST}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version that fixes a few issues with your suggestion.

The main change is that you need to reuse the capure `$1` in the second rewriting rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}  \.example\.net$
Rewriterule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404
```

Please note that I did not test this myself, I only applied a few fixes by looking over it.

That rule set will work likewise in the http server's host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"). You definitely should prefer the first option, except if you have no access to the configuration (read: a cheap hosting provider).

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded and enabled and if you decide to use a dynamic configuration file then take care that it is located in the host'd `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder and is readable by the http server process.